# Validation to check whether the textbox value is changed or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I want a validation that only allows alphanumeric characters,backspace,delete,space and special characters which can change the text box value from Kyeboard.I have tried like

```
$('#profile_pstate').on('keypress',function(e1){
    var cntry_key = e1.which;
    if(cntry_key == 8 || cntry_key == 46 || cntry_key == 32 || (cntry_key >= 48 && cntry_key <= 57) || (cntry_key >= 65 && cntry_key <= 90)) {   
        // For Backspace, Delete, Space, Numbers and Alphabets
        alert('success');
    }
});
```

But for the special characters how can I add them.If I add them manually they are not in a proper range like alphabets and numeric.Could you please suggest me a way to do it or even a correct way to do the validation.

Comment: `"alphanumeric characters,backspace,delete,space and special characters"` thats all we have in keyboard!

Comment: think of using Regular expression

Comment: @Bharadwaj what about on pressing tab,shift,alt,function keys?We need to skip them right?I want to accept only `alphanumeric characters,backspace,delete,space and special characters`

Comment: @Gautam3164 If you are going to restrict the tab, shift keys, how the user is going to move focus to another input control? Are you going to restrict the users to use only mouse to move to another input control. And in the same way, if you restrict shift, how the users are going to type the special characters like @,#,$, etc and in mixed case (usually users will key in capital letters by pressing the shift key, though caps lock is another option I don't think any one will use that option)

Comment: @Gautam3164 `keypress` event identify only `printable` keys! if you want to get `keycode` associated with all keys that you press, use `keydown`

Comment: @Gautam3164, can you list the special characters to be permitted as input ?

Comment: @Arvind all should be.

Comment: @Gautam3164, which characters you don't want to permit ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this for special characters

```
      function nospecialChars(field) {
         var val = document.getElementById(field);
        var iChars = "!@#$%^&amp;*()+=-[]\\\';,./{}|\":&lt;&gt;?";
        for (var i = 0; i < val.value.length; i++) {
            if (iChars.indexOf(val.value.charAt(i)) != -1) {
                alert("Special Characters are not allowed");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

On page textbox change method call function

```
    <input type="text" id="txt" onkeyup="validate(this.id)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try RegExp, below example allows alpha-numeric & spaces only:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#profile_pstate').on('input', function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\da-zA-Z\s]/g, '');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="profile_pstate" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried like

```
$('#profile_country').on('keypress',function(e1){
    var cntry_key = e1.which;
    var cntry_key_code = e1.keyCode;
    if( (cntry_key_code == 0 && cntry_key > 0 && !e1.ctrlKey) || (cntry_key == 0 && cntry_key_code == 46) || (cntry_key == 8) 
            || (e1.ctrlKey && cntry_key == 120) || (e1.ctrlKey && cntry_key == 118)
            || (e1.ctrlKey && cntry_key == 86) || (e1.ctrlKey && cntry_key == 88)) {
        $('#profile_pstate').val('');
    }
});
```

And it is working fine with `Alpha-Numeric, Special characters, Space, Backspace and Delete` and also `control` events like `ctrl+A` AND only works for cut(ctrl+x) and paste(ctrl+v).